# show dynamic data using checkbox in extjs

Tags: extjs

I have a combo box in which the user selects a value, that value is passed to the checkbox data store and it is populated dynamically from database (oracle). I tried the code below. It seems that the selected parameter is being passed to checkbox and I can see the data being populated on the console. I just can't render the checkbox on form. The error I get is: typeError: this.items[0] is undefined.

```
    testArray = new Array();
    var testStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
        proxy:new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
        method:'GET',
        prettyUrls:false,
        url:'kiu.htm',
        listeners:{
            'loadexception':{
            fn:test.form.data.loadException
            }
        }
        }),
        fields:["id", "display"],
        reader:new Ext.data.JsonReader({
        id:'id',
        root:'results',
        totalProperty:'totalCount',
        fields:new Ext.data.Record.create([
            {name:'id',type:'int'},
            {name:'display',type:'string'}
        ])
        }),
        listeners:{      
        load: function(t, records, options, success) {
            for(var i=0; i<records.length; i++) {
              testArray.push({name:records[i].data.id, boxLabel: records[i].data.display});
              alert(testArray[i].id);
            }
        }
        }
    });


    {
                         xtype:'combo',
                         id:'comboid3',                         
                         store:combostore,
                         displayField:'display',
                         valueField:'id',
                         tabIndex:1,
                         loadingText:'Loading combo...',
                         listeners :{
                                   select:function(event){
                                         testStore.baseParams = {
                                                "comboid":Ext.getCmp('comboid3').getValue()
                                            };                                        

                                         testStore.load();

                                    }
                         }

                   },
                   {


                                xtype:'checkboxgroup',
                                                         fieldLabel:'Check',                             
                               items:testArray
           }
```

Help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Specifying the Ext JS version is always going to be helpful.  It appears this must be 2.x or 3.x and not the current version.

The issue is timing, load calls are asynchronous so by attempting to utilize testArray in this fashion you are likely referencing an empty array by the time it parses the items property of your checkboxgroup.  You have a couple options around this... one is to grab a reference to the checkbox group and add the items into it, the other is to not put the checkbox group in the form at all until the call returns and then add it with the populated items array.  In either case it is likely that you will need to look up a component reference to either the FormPanel or the CheckboxGroup from within the load handler function and call the 'add' method to add child items.

Comment: Version is 3.1. I modified the code above. Now, I can see the data being populated in the checkbox store, I just can't render it on screen @Rich Waters